# Java GSON Escaping backslashes in a custom serializer

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, escaping

I need to serialize a Java LocalDate (e.g. 2020-02-04) into the following format:
`"myProperty":"\/Date(-2209165200000+0100)\/"`, as the interface we work with requests that format.
We are currently using the newest version of GSON (2.8.6)

Our custom LocalDate Serializer looks like this at the moment:

```
public class LocalDateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<LocalDate> {

  @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(LocalDate src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        Instant instant = src.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
        long timeInMillis = instant.toEpochMilli();
        ZoneOffset offset = OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset();
        return context.serialize("\\/Date(" + timeInMillis + offset + ")\\/");
    }
}
```

The issue now is that, as far as I know, that the `context.serialize` function escapes the double backslashes, so the final result is `"myProperty":"\\/Date(-2209165200000+0100)\\/"` instead of `"myProperty":"\/Date(-2209165200000+0100)\/"`
And in Java 1.8 you are not allowed to simply have a String like `"\/"`, as this will result in a compiler error.

Is there any simple way of getting our result with single backslashes?

Thanks and kind regards :)

Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed our problem by returning a new `JsonPrimitive` instead of using `context`

So we are using `return new JsonPrimitive("/Date(" + timeInMillis + offset + ")/");` now and everything works fine now. Still thanks for the input though, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As specified in [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7), `\/` represents an escaped forward slash and decodes to `\`.

Consequently, you want to return `context.serialize("/Date(" + timeInMillis + offset + ")/");`.